# How to find images with balanced brightness in OpenCV/JavaCV?

Tags: opencv, histogram, gaussian, javacv

i want to compare some similar images to find that one, which have  a balanced brighntess (not over or underexposed).

- My first idea was to get the average brightness of a image.For this i take a brightness histogram. But this method produce a lot of errors. Because there could be images which have only low and high brightness
- My second idea is to create a histogram which represent a gaussian distribution. But i don't know how to create a histogram with those values.

Have anybody an idea or another solution?

greetings

Comment: I don't quite understand. You say that you want to keep the images that have a well distributed histogram and compare those. Why don't you just discard the ones that are under- or over- exposed?? (The ones with high and low brightness)

Comment: i want to create a ranking of a set of similar images. I think the gaussian distribution represent a good histogram of brightness. If i have such kind of histogram, i could rank 2 images with Chi-Square-Method to get a score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution.
With [CvHistogram* cvMakeHistHeaderForArray(int dims, int* sizes, CvHistogram* hist, float* data, float** ranges=NULL, int uniform=1)](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_histograms.html#makehistheaderforarray) i can generate histograms with a table of values very easy.

greetings